# Save the file to Google App Script Google Drive and download it to your PC

Tags: google-apps-script, download, google-drive-api

I am using js in Google Spreadsheet to create and use a script that automates work.

I want to add one more feature, but it doesn't work.

Save the saved file to Google Drive in the current script
I want to download it to PC \ Download folder as well.

I need to do both, but I don't know what to add to the blob.
It's hard to get a sense even if you search Google Class and Stackflow.
Ask a question.
Can anyone help?

```
function sendEmail(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
      var range = sheet.getRange("A1:K");

      var tempSheet = ss.insertSheet(`Main_PDD_`);
      range.copyTo(tempSheet.getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
      range.copyTo(tempSheet.getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS, false);
      range.copyFormatToRange(tempSheet, 1, 1, 1, 1);
      var nick = tempSheet.getSheetValues(2,2,1,1);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();

      var tempSheetId = tempSheet.getSheetId();
      var spreadsheetName = tempSheet.getSheetName();
      
                        
      var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/export?format=xlsx&gid=" + tempSheetId ; // convert to excel

      // define date - pdd
      var date = new Date();
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      var pdd = Utilities.formatDate(date , "GMT+9", "yyyyMMdd") ;
       
      // Attachments
      var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        muteHttpExceptions: true
      });

      // Save to Google Drive
      var blobs = response.getBlob();
      blobs.setName(`${spreadsheetName}${pdd}.xlsx`)
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1Q3yA7BzqRSOGxw9ABe1oMaaweggwwe-0');
      backupFile = folder.createFile(blobs);

      Browser.msgBox(`${spreadsheetName}${pdd} Upload Complete.`, Browser.Buttons.OK);


      // delete temporary sheet
      ss.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
}
```

Add.

Because the account is using G-suit
Google Spreadsheet in cell "N3"

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:khan@123.com?
&subject=Main List
&body=
Hello%0D%0AThank you.%0D%0A
From "&B2&"."
," Send Email")
```

I put it in and use it.

I'm using the question script and two hyperlinks.
I want to combine them into one task.

Is there a way to run the script above to upload to Google Drive & download to PC and execute the hyperlink?
Any way to insert hyperlink in google script please help me

Comment: It is possible to obtain the download link programmatically, but it is not possible to execute this download link programmatically to download the file.

Comment: @ziganotschka It would be difficult to apply both with just a script, right? I keep searching on the website, but it's hard to find the right code.

Comment: It is not difficult - it is impossible to download a fiel to your local machine with Google Apps Script. You need to do it either in a different programming language like e.g. Java or apply a workaround as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382041/download-file-from-drive-using-appscript) where the file can be downloaded by opening a website in a browser.

Comment: @ziganotschka Thank you. I'll have to try and think about it again.
Thank you again.